# Get all the document excluding Document sets using REST API In SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, sharepoint-rest-api, document, document-set

I need a REST API for getting the Items excluding the Document sets

Please help me on this.

I got the problem, Few Documentsets content Type is not "Documentset". Because of this only data which is having Documnetset is coming with the below API:

```
https://SiteURL/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('LibraryName')/items?$select=ID,Title&$filter=ContentType eq Document Set
```

As Documentset is having contenttype other than "Document Set"
1.how to achieve the documentset are in the library
2.API for Excluding Document sets.

Thanks

Comment: Hi, does below answer work for you now?

Answer (score 2):

You can get items from document library except document sets using SharePoint REST endpoint like below:

```
https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/SPConnect/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('DocumentSets')/items?$select=Title&$filter=ContentType ne 'Document Set'
```

Where `Document Set` is the name of your content type.

Comment: Thanks For the reply. But this API is givng DOcument sets too

Comment: You have to use the correct name of your document set content type in filter query.

Comment: Ganesh , Given API is working for some library and now working for some other library.Not sure the reason, is there any other alternative to achieve this

Comment: Can you add screenshot of content type names/settings where this is not working? Add it to your original question by editing it. I will have a look. Also, you can fetch based on remaining content types like contenttype eq 'document' or contenttype eq 'folder'. You can include required content types as per your requirements.

Comment: Few Documentsets are customized using different Content type, Base is Document set Contenttype. using contenttypeid I resolved the issues.Thanks

Comment: Great, glad it worked for you!

Comment: For the DocumentSet conetenttype is customized so we are not getting this content type when we use REST API given by you

Comment: When you create a new content type based on default "Document Set" content type, you provide new name to that content type. For example you named it as "My Custom Document Set". Then, you have to use that name in API like:  `https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/SPConnect/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('DocumentSets')/items?$select=Title&$filter=ContentType ne 'My Custom Document Set'`. This way endpoint given in my answer will work without using any content type ID.

Comment: I am checking to see how things are going there on this issue.